# JSF2 Tomcat Session Backup for High Availability

Tags: session, jsf, tomcat, replication, high-availability

I'm very interested in how other users of clustered Tomcat servers running JSF2 applications are setting up session replication or other successful failover strategies for their clustered application.

In JSF 1.2 we have been using memcached session manager which I like because it scales well by avoiding all to all replication but we've been experiencing de-serialization errors after updating to JSF2. We may stick w/ msm and fix the serialization issues but I thought this would be a good time to poll the wider community and see how other JSF2 users are managing replication/backup in case there is an easier and better supported path to HA that is widely utilized.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!